# How to secure Resource or controller route in Laravel and Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, laravel

I am integrating laravel and backbone. I have routes like 
Route::resource('tasks', 'TaskController'); and backbone model uses this route for get, post and put requests. and this route simply displays raw data. I want to hide/secure this link/url so that users can't see raw data.How can I achieve this??

Comment: Just an update When I access link localhost/tasks it shows all the data from database i.e. [{"task_id":724,"name":"Task12","description":null,"priority":1,"assigned_to":6,‌​"},{"task_id":725,"name":"Task","description":null,"priority":1,"assigned_to":7,"‌​}

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : **you can't**.

If your Backbone application can access to something, a user can access to. For your server, backbone requests are exactly like a user requests. In fact, the browser make this requests for both.

You could put a password in your Backbone code to protect the access... but it's useless because the Backbone code is public (it is client side).

The only thing you can do is to put restrictions on what Backbone (or a user) can see. For example, authenticate the user and verify that he is allowed to access data before to send it.

If your Backbone app can access data there is no reason to hide them to your users. It's like if you want to hide the raw html code in a web site, that's senseless !